# Import Module From Another Project

Tags: python

i am trying to import a function in BlueZone\queries.py into items.py in another project. I have researched a ton here on stackoverflow and got answers to use sys.path.insert but I am still getting the error below.

folder structure

```
Project 1 :
BlueZone
-auto.py
-queries.py

project 2:
susp_items
-items.py
```

items.py

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(r'C:\Users\bxt058y\PycharmProjects\BlueZone'))

from queries import func1
```

error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'func1' from 'queries' (C:\Users\USERNAME\PycharmProjects\BlueZone\queries.py)
```

Comment: Your error is specifiying that it can't find the ```func1``` but its able to access the queries module - Cross check if the soecified function ```func1``` is inside the queries module or not.

Comment: not sure because i think there is a python library called queries...because when I try to find its functions for that library other functions come out that i dont have in my queries.py file..

Comment: I think its still pointing to your ```Bluezone\queries``` file only since in the error log the queries file path is mentioned clearly